# How do I fix Firebase Auth only working after refresh?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuex

I'm using Firebase's `signInWithEmailAndPassword`function in order to authenticate, then saving an access_token in localStorage so that a Vuex getter that I've built detects that the user is logged in, and finally I'm making the router go to a Vue component that in the router has `requiresAuth: true`.

However, it isn't working because apparently the loggedIn getter will only be changed after I refresh the page.

I've already built my register and logout functions correctly, but this one doesn't seem to be working despite using the same code structure which is: 
-Call firebase's auth function
-Then call a promise which has the router redirection inside
-Finally (outside the promise) do the querying if applicable (add user to the database when registering).

The closest I've gotten to is using this slightly alternate structure:

```
login () {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  alert(error.code);
  alert(error.message);

  // ...

});
let token = (firebase.auth().currentUser.refreshToken)
localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
console.log('firebase token: ', token)
this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
}
```

What I would expect is that I get redirected to the component that requires authentication. This is done after I refresh and click on the 'Home' button (which requires `loggedIn`to be true).

How do I make it work without the refresh?

Answer (score 1):

To detect changes in the user's authentication state, use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener as shown in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

This callback will fire when the user's explicit sign-in completes, but also when the page reloads.